# How to measure Time between a start of an activity and stop?

Tags: java, android, performance, time

I thought maybe it could work with startactivityforresult, but no idea how..? After the measure I want this time to show up on another activity.

I have tried this so far:

In the Main activity:

```
 public class MainScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btn_start;
TextView textview1;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);


    btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    btn_start.setOnClickListener(this);
    textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    textview1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("time"));

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,Game.class), 0);

}
```

}

and in the activity, where i want to stop the time:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button start_time;

int i = 0;
TextView textview1;

Button RelativeLayout;
Button gameover;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout.setClickable(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
      start_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_time);
      start_time.setOnClickListener(this);
      textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      gameover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gameover);


      gameover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();


            }


            });



}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override


public void onClick(View v) {


//Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_time);
    Random r = new Random();
    RelativeLayout decorView = (RelativeLayout) start_time.getParent();
    int screenWidth = decorView.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = decorView.getHeight();
      long startTime =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
      i++;
/*  
        Random r = new Random();

    int x = r.nextInt(R.id.wrap_content);
      int y = r.nextInt(R.id.wrap_content);




    b.setX(x);  
    b.setY(y);
     */ 

    if (i == 1 ) {

        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 2 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 3 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 4 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 5 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 6 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    else if (i == 7) {
        long difference = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()  - startTime;

          Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, MainScreen.class);
          intent.putExtra("time",difference);
         // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getIntent().getStringExtra("time"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          textview1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("time"));
        finish();
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove following line from your code

```
sec.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and in onClick(-)

```
startTime=System.currentTimeInMillis();
```

And in

```
sec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

         totalTime=System.currentTimeInMillis()-startTime;

          Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, MainScreen.class);
          intent.putExtra("time",totalTime);
          startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

And in MainScreen call

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("time");
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thank you :D I wanted to go back to the main activity after I clicked the sec button. can't I do that like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

// your activity start/stop

long endTime = System.nanoTime(); // save this time in SharedPreference and get in second activity
```

Comment: Thank you! how can I use the shared preference?

Comment: you have already accepted someone answer. If it is a new question, ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the listener twice; second time it overrides the first listener which never gets called.

Comment: Thanks! :) ..where exactly?

Comment: Here: `sec.setOnClickListener(this);`

         `sec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`